# How to work on a Checkout

Tags: carthage

I have a main project where I have some parts in a Framework(Separation of concerns). This framework is added to the main project via Carthage.

> Cartfile:

```
git "https://Bitbucket.org/nameofproject.git"
```

Then I run:

```
carthage update --platform iOS
```

Now working on the main project, I need to make changes to the framework used and installed via Carthage. How will you do that, `git init` on the checkout project from Carthage?

Any input is appreciated, thanks